# how to setup a symlink for /var/www on a local server to point at a folder on the host?

Tags: ubuntu, webserver

I've setup a local server running on ubuntu using VMWare Fusion and managed to get everything going really nicely, but I can't figure out to setup the symlink (I'm guessing thats whats needed here) to link /var/www where my server currently looks for files at the folder on the computer that is hosting it.

I'm running OS X Lion and Ubuntu 12.04 if that helps.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.  Perhaps if you were to specify what you are actually trying to do, rather than how to implement a possible solution that may not even be correct. Are you trying to put your website files in a different directory (if so, you don't need to use /var/www at all)?  Are you trying to link to /var/www from another computer (you could mount it if you wanted)?

Comment: My apologies. I have got a local server up and running and the files for this are currently stored in /var/www. I wish to store these files in a folder on my host machine instead. Is that any clearer?

Comment: Since I don't have a Mac or VMware, I don't think I can post an answer.  I would urge you to use a conventional method of keeping the files on the server and accessing them remotely via either ssh or ftp.  Many editors support this.  You can't directly link to a remote directory, but you could mount it first, using either sshfs or smb (cifs), then link to the mounted directory.  Either one is a bit of work to get authentication and permissions working correctly.

Comment: As I understand it, what I'm trying to do is in fact a popular method, I'm just struggling to find any documentation on it. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after hour several hours of hunting and trying things, here was the solution to my problem:

VMware Tools not installing properly.

I had to run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Then I could finally run

```
sudo vmware-config-tools.pl
```

This installed the tools properly and mounted the shared folder where I wished to place my files. All thats left is to simply symlink to it. Hope that helps anyone who has the same problem in the future.